# Tomcat with SSL

Tags: tomcat, ssl, active-directory, certificate, keytool

I'm trying to add SSL in tomcat, using certificates obtained from the AD Server.

I used the MMC tool to obtain my personal certificate, an intermediate certificate and the root certificate, of the active directory.

These are the commands that I used to import them on a keystore:

```
keytool -import -trustcacert -alias root -file rootcert.cer -keystore keystore
keytool -import -trustcacert -alias intermediate -file intercert.cer -keystore keystore
keytool -import -trustcacert -alias nunocert -file nunocert.cer -keystore keystore
```

With that done, I altered the server.xml and added this:

```
<Connector port="8443" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" 
 SSLEnabled="true"   keystoreFile="D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/conf/keystore.jks" 
 keystorePass="password" clientAuth="false" 
 keyAlias="nunocert" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

After restarting and trying to access

```
https://localhost:8443
```

I always get connection refused.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is port 8443 open in the server firewall? Can you telnet to that host:port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a keystore with the private key for Tomcat.
What you have done is import various certificates from your computer to a keystore.
Either extract your private key into a PKCS12 bundle and then set it to tomcat `storetype=pkcs12` or create a keystore for use for tomcat

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

I didn't understand very well your options.

In the MMC tool, I can't export my private keys, the option is disabled.

As for your second suggestion, I create the keystore and then what?

Thanks in advance,
Nuno.

Comment: Sorry for double comment, couldn't edit in time. I create a keystore and then import those 3 certificates? Or stick with the self-signed certificate?

Comment: You can create a key-pair using keytool i.e. a self-signed certificate for Tomcat and the set that in the `server.xml` connector configuration

Comment: Nothing here explains 'connection refused'.

Comment: @EJP:It does. Since the connector is down due to the missing private key.

Comment: @user384706, thank you. I managed to do it with a self-signed certificate :)

Answer (score 0):

The configuration seems to be correct.  Which broser are you using?  Try adding root and intermediate certificates in the browser manually and see if that helps.  If it doesn't help, restart JBoss with the VM parameter **-Dssl.debug=true** and check your server logs for additional information related to this failure.

Comment: Hi Helios, sorry but I am not using JBOSS. I tried both with Google Chrome and Internet Explorer.